# In what sense does the Maclaurin series for $\ln(x+1)$ converge on $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

This is regarding Modes of Convergence. The question is as follows.

> > Given $f(x) = \ln(x+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$. Let $f_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ Determine whether $f_N$ converges pointwise, uniformly, or in the $L^2$ sense to $f$ on $-1\leq x\leq1$.

I am having a hard time determining whether or not $f_N(x)$ does converge pointwise, uniformly, or in the $L^2$ sense to $f(x)$

I know $|f(x)-f_N(x)|\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$ for every $x$ in $-1<x<1$; however, I am not sure whether it converges pointwise or uniformly on the closed interval $[-1,1]$. The end point $-1$ is what causes the complications here. I want to say on the close interval, it does not converge uniformly because for all $\epsilon>0$, there does not exist a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|f(x)-f_N(x)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $x \in [-1,1].$

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pde] tag and the phrase "Partial differential equations" from the title since the question isn't related to that kind of thing (even though it may have been assigned in a PDEs course).

Comment: In regards to the question: can you check to make sure there isn't a typo in the part "on $-1 \leq x \leq 1$"?  $\ln(x+1)$ isn't defined for $x = -1$, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about convergence on the closed interval.

Comment: No, it isn't a typo. I am aware $\ln(x+1)$ isn't defined for $x=-1$ and this is why I am having difficulties with this problem.

Comment: You can change your previous question to include your thoughts if you'd like, but try not to ask the same question twice.